# How does this lemma imply this external cross product?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

From Rotman's Algebraic Topology:  I'm trying to understand this proof but I'm having trouble understanding what's inside the red box at the bottom of the image.

The line says that Lemma $12.28$ (also included at the bottom of the picture) implies that $t^*(v \times u') = (-1)^{mp} u' \times v$ but I don't see how the lemma implies this.

$$v \times u' \in H^{m+p}(Y \times X; R) \text{ and } u' \times v \in H^{m+p}(X \times Y ; R)$$

$$t : X \times Y \rightarrow Y \times X \text{ so } t^* : H^*(Y \times X ; R) \rightarrow H^*(X \times Y; R)$$

But the lemma only applies to complexes of the form $S_* \otimes S_*$, which $H^*(Y \times X; R)$ is not in the form of.

Can someone explain why this is valid in the proof?

[image]

Comment: $t$ is defined on homology. Choose a pair of cochains $v$, $u$ and an arbitrary pair of chains $\alpha, \beta$ and try evaluating $t^*(v\times u)(\alpha\otimes\beta)$ explicitly. This will tell you what $t^*$ does on cohomology, and so give you what you need.

Comment: @Tyrone Can you explain how to evaluate $t^*(v \times u)(\alpha \times \beta)$ explicitly?  If $t^*:H^*(Y \times X; R) \rightarrow H^*(X \times Y;R)$ and if $u,v$ are cochains then it doesn't seem that $v \times u $ is in the domain of $t^*$.

Comment: $t^*:S^*(Y)\otimes S^*(X)\rightarrow S^*(X)\otimes S^*(Y)$ is contravariant. $(t^*(u\times v))(\alpha\times \beta))=(u\times v)(t_*(\alpha\times \beta))$

Comment: @Tyrone If $t: X \times Y \rightarrow Y \times X$, why is $t^*$ defined as $t^ * : S^*(Y) \otimes S^*(X) \rightarrow S^*(X) \otimes S^*(Y)$ and not $t^* : H^*(Y \times X; R) \rightarrow H^*(X \times Y;R)$?

Comment: how does your map not have the right domain, then? The diagonal $\Delta_{X\times Y}$ on $X\times Y$ maps to $X\times Y\times X\times Y$

Comment: I realize now I misinterpreted the word cochains for something else.  So assuming $t^* : H^*(Y \times X;R) \rightarrow H^*(X \times Y;R)$, how would you show that $t(v \times u') = -1^{mp} u' \times v?  I don't understand how that map shows this relationship.

Comment: For arbitrary $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we get $(t^*(u\times v))(\alpha\times \beta)=(u\times v)t_*(\alpha\times \beta)=(-1)^{pq}(u\times v)(\beta \times \alpha)=(-1)^{pq}u(\beta)\cdot v(\alpha)=(-1)^{pq}(v\times u)(\alpha\times \beta)$.

Comment: @Tyrone Why is $t_*$ the map in Lemma $12.28$?  If $t : X \times Y \rightarrow Y \times X$, then $t_* :S_*(X \times Y) \rightarrow S_*(Y \times X)$ which is not in the form $S_* \otimes S_* \rightarrow S_* \otimes S_*$

Comment: Use the definition of the external cross product on pg 400.

Comment: @Tyrone I can't see how the definition explains why $t_*$ is the map of Lemma $12.28$.  Can you explain it?